# Passing a param to build a JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I pass the subCategory in as an parameter for the function? I have a working solution just passing in the param and then having a switch do the work to make the JSON.subcategory read from the right place. However I feel like there is some thing I am missing on making this more functional, or OO friendly.

So is there a way to make the passed param understand its a variable and not the object literal.

```
json = {
  weather: ["rain", "snow","sun"],
  news: ["events", "local","world"]
}

messageBuilder(weather)

function messageBuilder(passedVariable){
  var object = json.passedVariable;
  // object = json.weather
  console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
}
```

Also am I using the terms correctly? I tried to search google for an answer and ended up not really finding anything.

Comment: You can call `messageBuilder(json.weather)`, and then `JSON.stringify(passedVariable)`

Comment: What would be an example of a "subCatgory" here? An item in the `weather` / `news` list?

Comment: @James . The weather and news are the subCategories and the full use case would be to call upon them based on the count. So last line would become something like object[count]

Comment: @whatkai so does `messageBuilder` really need to know about `json` in this case? Why can't you just call `messageBuilder(json.weather)`? Or do you receive the sub category as a variable? Not really seeing the need for the closure here.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the object property key name (sub category) in as a string and use bracket notation to pick it from the data in the function.

Note: that's an object, not JSON, so I've named it as such in the example.

```js
const obj = {
  weather: ["rain", "snow", "sun"],
  news: ["events", "local", "world"]
};

messageBuilder('weather');

function messageBuilder(subCat){
  var object = obj[subCat];
  console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code a little bit:

```
     json = {
            weather : [
                "rain", "snow","sun"
            ],
            news : [
                "events", "local","world"
            ]

        }

        messageBuilder('weather');

        function messageBuilder(passedVariable){

        var object = json[passedVariable];
             // object = json.weather
            console.log(object);

        }
```

First of all you should pass your parameter as a string. Then just pull out the property from the object using object['property']